# Convert Files Async by using ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, ms-word, office-automation, export-to-pdf, python-watchdog

I have this code that I am using to convert doc files to `pdf`, but I feel like it is not doing the correct job. I want this code to be able to handle as many files as possible at the same time when I put them in the directory.

```
import os
import time
import pythoncom
from win32com import client
from docx.shared import Pt
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import shutil

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import concurrent.futures


baseAd = r"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\utkuploads"
fileList = []
max_processes = os.cpu_count() or 1
max_threads = os.cpu_count() or 1
def createText(filename, filedetail):
    with open(r"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\utkuploads\{filename}.txt".format(filename=filename), 'w') as f:
        f.write(f'{filedetail}')

def doc2pdf(doc_name, pdf_name, font_size=8):
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    word = client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
    if os.path.exists(pdf_name):
        os.remove(pdf_name)
    worddoc = word.Documents.Open(doc_name, ReadOnly=1)
    worddoc.Content.Font.Size = font_size
    try:
        worddoc.SaveAs(pdf_name, FileFormat=17)
    except Exception as e:
        createText('wordToPdfException', f"{e}")
    worddoc.Close()
    # Quit the Word application
    word.Quit()
    pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
    return pdf_name


class DocFileHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def is_temporary_file(event, filename):
        return filename.startswith("~$")

    def on_created(self, event):
        if not (self.is_temporary_file(os.path.basename(event.src_path)) or event.src_path.endswith(
                '.tmp') or event.is_directory or os.path.basename(event.src_path).startswith("~$")):
            fileList.append(event)

def outer_is_temporary_file(filename):
    return filename.startswith("~$")

def createFolder(baseAd, folderName):
    path = os.path.join(baseAd, folderName)
    isExist = os.path.exists(path)

    try:
        if not isExist:
            os.makedirs(path)
        return path
    except:
        return path

def createFolderAtt(folderName):
    isExist = os.path.exists(folderName)
    try:
        if not isExist:
            os.makedirs(folderName)
        return folderName
    except:
        return folderName

def mainConverter(event):
    # The first [0] is root directory utkuploads the second is the file name with extension.
    currentFileName = os.path.split(event.src_path)
    currentFileNameSplitted = os.path.split(event.src_path)[-1]
    try:
        ## This part needs to work for the files that needs to be converted to PDF.
        ## It catches DOCX files and takes their location by doc_path and creates a fake pdf_path directory

        if event.event_type == 'created' and event.src_path.lower().endswith(
                '.docx') and '@' not in currentFileNameSplitted and not outer_is_temporary_file(
                event.src_path):
            print(f"{currentFileName} STARTED")

            doc_path = event.src_path
            pdf_path = os.path.splitext(doc_path)[0] + '.pdf'

            # print(f'Doc path: {doc_path}, \nPdf path: {pdf_path}')

            # If '_' in doc_path
            if '_' in doc_path:
                print(f'New Template has been detected: {doc_path}')
                return
            # If file is not temporary, not _ (template), not attachment, not TEMPLATE-REPORT
            elif '~$' not in doc_path and '_' not in doc_path and '@' not in doc_path and 'TEMPLATE-REPORT' not in doc_path:

                # print(f"File will be converted here: {doc_path}")
                try:
                    if '-GENERATED-REPORT' in doc_path:
                        # Here pdf convertion happens.
                        doc2pdf(doc_path, pdf_path)
                        # Create subFolder based on PDF file.
                        createFolderPath = os.path.split(pdf_path)[-1].split(".")[0]
                        createFolderPath = createFolderPath.replace('-GENERATED-REPORT', '')

                        try:
                            newFolderPath = createFolder(baseAd, createFolderPath)
                        except Exception as error:
                            createText('createFolderGeneratedReport', f'{error}')

                        # print(f"New folder has been created: {newFolderPath}")
                        pdfFileName = os.path.split(pdf_path)[-1]

                        src_pdf = pdf_path
                        dest_pathPdf = os.path.join(newFolderPath, pdfFileName)
                        shutil.move(src_pdf, dest_pathPdf)
                        # print(f"File has been moved to its destination. src: {src_pdf}, destination: {dest_pathPdf} ")

                        # print('Doc path', doc_path)
                        wordFileName = os.path.split(doc_path)[-1]
                        wordPdf = wordFileName
                        dest_pathWord = os.path.join(newFolderPath, wordPdf)
                        shutil.move(doc_path, dest_pathWord)

                    # print( f"Generated Rapor File has been moved to its destination. src: {doc_path}, destination: {dest_pathWord} ")

                    elif '-IMZALIRAPOR' in doc_path:
                        # Here pdf convertion happens.
                        doc2pdf(doc_path, pdf_path)
                        # Create subFolder based on PDF file.
                        createFolderPath = os.path.split(pdf_path)[-1].split(".")[0]
                        createFolderPath = createFolderPath.replace('-IMZALIRAPOR', '')

                        try:
                            newFolderPath = createFolder(baseAd, createFolderPath)
                        except Exception as error:
                            createText('CreateFolderImzaliRapor', f'{error}')
                        # print(f"New folder has been created: {newFolderPath}")
                        pdfFileName = os.path.split(pdf_path)[-1]

                        src_pdf = pdf_path
                        dest_pathPdf = os.path.join(newFolderPath, pdfFileName)
                        shutil.move(src_pdf, dest_pathPdf)
                        # print(f"File has been moved to its destination. src: {src_pdf}, destination: {dest_pathPdf} ")

                        # print('Doc path', doc_path)
                        wordFileName = os.path.split(doc_path)[-1]
                        wordPdf = wordFileName
                        dest_pathWord = os.path.join(newFolderPath, wordPdf)
                        shutil.move(doc_path, dest_pathWord)

                        # print(f"Imzali Report File has been moved to its destination. src: {doc_path}, destination: {dest_pathWord} ")


                    elif 'GENERATED-REPORT' not in doc_path and '-IMZALIRAPOR' not in doc_path and '@' not in doc_path:
                        # Here pdf convertion happens.
                        doc2pdf(doc_path, pdf_path)
                        # Create subFolder based on PDF file.
                        createFolderPath = os.path.split(pdf_path)[-1].split(".")[0]

                        try:
                            newFolderPath = createFolder(baseAd, createFolderPath)
                        except Exception as error:
                            createText('buAnaModel', f'{error}')

                        # print(f"New folder has been created: {newFolderPath}")
                        pdfFileName = os.path.split(pdf_path)[-1]

                        src_pdf = pdf_path
                        dest_pathPdf = os.path.join(newFolderPath, pdfFileName)
                        shutil.move(src_pdf, dest_pathPdf)
                        # print(f"File has been moved to its destination. src: {src_pdf}, destination: {dest_pathPdf} ")

                        # print('Doc path', doc_path)
                        wordFileName = os.path.split(doc_path)[-1]
                        wordPdf = wordFileName
                        dest_pathWord = os.path.join(newFolderPath, wordPdf)
                        shutil.move(doc_path, dest_pathWord)

                        # print(f"File has been moved to its destination. src: {doc_path}, destination: {dest_pathWord} ")

                except Exception as e:
                    createText('exceptionHasOccured...', f'{e}')

            print(f"{currentFileName} FINISHED")

        elif event.event_type == 'created' and '@' in currentFileNameSplitted and not outer_is_temporary_file(
                event.src_path):
            print(f"{currentFileName} ATTACHMENT STARTED")

            doc_path = event.src_path
            folderPath = currentFileNameSplitted.split("@")[1].split(".")[0]

            try:
                baseFolderPath = os.path.split(doc_path)[:-1][0]
                # print(f"Attachments detected: {doc_path}, {currentFileNameSplitted}, {baseFolderPath}")
                dest_path = os.path.join(baseFolderPath, folderPath, currentFileNameSplitted)
                try:
                    shutil.move(doc_path, dest_path)
                    print(f"{currentFileName} ATTACHMENT MOVED")
                except:
                    try:
                        createFolderAtt(os.path.join(baseFolderPath, folderPath))
                        shutil.move(doc_path, dest_path)
                        print(f"{currentFileName} ATTACHMENT MOVED")
                    except Exception as e:
                        createText('InnerAttachmentError', f'{e}')
            except Exception as e:
                createText('outerAttachmentErrorOccured', f'{e}')

    except Exception as e:
        createText('outerAllExceptionasOccured', f'{e}')

def main():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_processes) as executor:

    #with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_processes) as executor:
        while True:
            if fileList:
                file_to_process = fileList.pop()
                print('File has been sent', file_to_process)
                executor.submit(mainConverter, file_to_process)

    """with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_threads) as executor:
        while True:
            if fileList:
                file_to_process = fileList.pop()
                print('File has been sent', file_to_process)
                executor.submit(mainConverter, file_to_process)"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    directory_to_watch = r"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\utkuploads"
    event_handler = DocFileHandler()

    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path=directory_to_watch, recursive=False)
    observer.start()

    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:

        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

I have tried using three different ones the best performing one is ProcessPoolExecutor, but it doesn't convert files at the same time. It doesn't open up like 5 WORD and converts them `async`.

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_processes) as executor:
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_processes) as executor:
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_threads) as executor:
```

What am I doing wrong?

@Booboo
Reply to Booboo:
I have done the same. Run the code and copied few files to the folder but they got stuck in here.

```
Hit Enter to terminate: <FileCreatedEvent: event_type=created, src_path='C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads\\4321-1705055733693-GENERATED-REPORT.docx', is_directory=False> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\utkuploads\4321-1705055733693-GENERATED-REPORT.docx
File has been sent <FileCreatedEvent: event_type=created, src_path='C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads\\4321-1705055733693-GENERATED-REPORT.docx', is_directory=False>
<FileCreatedEvent: event_type=created, src_path='C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads\\4321-1705055677609.docx', is_directory=False> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\utkuploads\4321-1705055677609.docx
File has been sent <FileCreatedEvent: event_type=created, src_path='C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads\\4321-1705055677609.docx', is_directory=False>
<FileCreatedEvent: event_type=created, src_path='C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads\\4321-1705055677609-GENERATED-REPORT.docx', is_directory=False> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\utkuploads\4321-1705055677609-GENERATED-REPORT.docx
File has been sent <FileCreatedEvent: event_type=created, src_path='C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads\\4321-1705055677609-GENERATED-REPORT.docx', is_directory=False>
<FileCreatedEvent: event_type=created, src_path='C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads\\4321-1705055683658-GENERATED-REPORT.docx', is_directory=False> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\utkuploads\4321-1705055683658-GENERATED-REPORT.docx
File has been sent <FileCreatedEvent: event_type=created, src_path='C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads\\4321-1705055683658-GENERATED-REPORT.docx', is_directory=False>
<FileCreatedEvent: event_type=created, src_path='C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads\\4321-1705055733693.docx', is_directory=False> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\utkuploads\4321-1705055733693.docx
File has been sent <FileCreatedEvent: event_type=created, src_path='C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads\\4321-1705055733693.docx', is_directory=False>



Then i hit enter and this conversions happend:

('C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads', '4321-1705055683658.docx') STARTED
('C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads', '4321-1705055683658-GENERATED-REPORT.docx') STARTED
('C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads', '4321-1705055733693.docx') STARTED
('C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads', '4321-1705055733693-GENERATED-REPORT.docx') STARTED
('C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads', '4321-1705055677609.docx') STARTED
('C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads', '4321-1705055677609-GENERATED-REPORT.docx') STARTED
('C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads', '4321-1705055683658-GENERATED-REPORT.docx') FINISHED
('C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads', '4321-1705055683658.docx') FINISHED
('C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads', '4321-1705055733693.docx') FINISHED
('C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads', '4321-1705055733693-GENERATED-REPORT.docx') FINISHED
('C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads', '4321-1705055677609.docx') FINISHED
('C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\utkuploads', '4321-1705055677609-GENERATED-REPORT.docx') FINISHED
```

Comment: Automation of MS Word is not the best way of implementing the required task. Consider using third-party components that don't require MS Word installed on the system instead. Be aware, if you run the code from any service or unattended you may face with problems.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev What should be the best approach for a task like this? Could you give me anywhere?

Comment: As I wrote above, consider using third-party components that don't require MS Word installed on the system instead.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev As far as i know there is LibreOffice version which again uses com by internally. Is there any third-party components that you can suggest to me?

Comment: In the code I see that MS Office Word is automated, so I wrote about possible consequences. And I can't really advertise anything there to you. You can google for any components on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your function `main` loops continuously checking whether there is anything in `fileList`. This is non-productive and *may* be preventing your event handler thread from being able to add new files to `fileList` in a timely fashion since the event handler thread and main thread cannot run in parallel due to both needing to first acquire the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) before they can execute. Instead, give your event handler that detects new files being created access to the multiprocessing pool so that it can directly submit new conversion tasks when it detects newly created files.

Try the following but please first review everything before running to be sure I didn't erroneously change anything (I have attempted to introduce a few other efficiencies and messages):

```py
import os
import time
import pythoncom
from win32com import client
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import shutil

USE_MULTIPROCESSING = True

if USE_MULTIPROCESSING:
    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as PoolExecutor
else:
    from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as PoolExecutor

baseAd = r"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\utkuploads"

def createText(filename, filedetail):
    with open(rf"{baseAd}\{filename}.txt", 'w') as f:
        f.write(f'{filedetail}')

def doc2pdf(doc_name, pdf_name, font_size=8):
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    word = client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
    if os.path.exists(pdf_name):
        os.remove(pdf_name)
    worddoc = word.Documents.Open(doc_name, ReadOnly=1)
    worddoc.Content.Font.Size = font_size
    try:
        worddoc.SaveAs(pdf_name, FileFormat=17)
    except Exception as e:
        createText('wordToPdfException', f"{e}")
    worddoc.Close()
    # Quit the Word application
    word.Quit()
    pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
    return pdf_name

def outer_is_temporary_file(filename):
    return filename.startswith("~$")

def createFolder(baseAd, folderName):
    path = os.path.join(baseAd, folderName)
    isExist = os.path.exists(path)

    try:
        if not isExist:
            os.makedirs(path)
        return path
    except:
        return path

def createFolderAtt(folderName):
    isExist = os.path.exists(folderName)
    try:
        if not isExist:
            os.makedirs(folderName)
        return folderName
    except:
        return folderName

def mainConverter(event):
    file_to_process = event.src_path
    # The first [0] is root directory utkuploads the second is the file name with extension.
    currentFileName = os.path.split(file_to_process)
    currentFileNameSplitted = os.path.split(file_to_process)[-1]
    try:
        ## This part needs to work for the files that needs to be converted to PDF.
        ## It catches DOCX files and takes their location by doc_path and creates a fake pdf_path directory

        if event.event_type == 'created' and file_to_process.lower().endswith(
                '.docx') and '@' not in currentFileNameSplitted and not outer_is_temporary_file(
                file_to_process):
            print(f"{currentFileName} STARTED")

            doc_path = file_to_process
            pdf_path = os.path.splitext(doc_path)[0] + '.pdf'

            # print(f'Doc path: {doc_path}, \nPdf path: {pdf_path}')

            # If '_' in doc_path
            if '_' in doc_path:
                print(f'New Template has been detected: {doc_path}')
                return
            # If file is not temporary, not _ (template), not attachment, not TEMPLATE-REPORT
            elif '~$' not in doc_path and '_' not in doc_path and '@' not in doc_path and 'TEMPLATE-REPORT' not in doc_path:

                # print(f"File will be converted here: {doc_path}")
                try:
                    if '-GENERATED-REPORT' in doc_path:
                        # Here pdf convertion happens.
                        doc2pdf(doc_path, pdf_path)
                        # Create subFolder based on PDF file.
                        createFolderPath = os.path.split(pdf_path)[-1].split(".")[0]
                        createFolderPath = createFolderPath.replace('-GENERATED-REPORT', '')

                        try:
                            newFolderPath = createFolder(baseAd, createFolderPath)
                        except Exception as error:
                            createText('createFolderGeneratedReport', f'{error}')

                        # print(f"New folder has been created: {newFolderPath}")
                        pdfFileName = os.path.split(pdf_path)[-1]

                        src_pdf = pdf_path
                        dest_pathPdf = os.path.join(newFolderPath, pdfFileName)
                        shutil.move(src_pdf, dest_pathPdf)
                        # print(f"File has been moved to its destination. src: {src_pdf}, destination: {dest_pathPdf} ")

                        # print('Doc path', doc_path)
                        wordFileName = os.path.split(doc_path)[-1]
                        wordPdf = wordFileName
                        dest_pathWord = os.path.join(newFolderPath, wordPdf)
                        shutil.move(doc_path, dest_pathWord)

                    # print( f"Generated Rapor File has been moved to its destination. src: {doc_path}, destination: {dest_pathWord} ")

                    elif '-IMZALIRAPOR' in doc_path:
                        # Here pdf convertion happens.
                        doc2pdf(doc_path, pdf_path)
                        # Create subFolder based on PDF file.
                        createFolderPath = os.path.split(pdf_path)[-1].split(".")[0]
                        createFolderPath = createFolderPath.replace('-IMZALIRAPOR', '')

                        try:
                            newFolderPath = createFolder(baseAd, createFolderPath)
                        except Exception as error:
                            createText('CreateFolderImzaliRapor', f'{error}')
                        # print(f"New folder has been created: {newFolderPath}")
                        pdfFileName = os.path.split(pdf_path)[-1]

                        src_pdf = pdf_path
                        dest_pathPdf = os.path.join(newFolderPath, pdfFileName)
                        shutil.move(src_pdf, dest_pathPdf)
                        # print(f"File has been moved to its destination. src: {src_pdf}, destination: {dest_pathPdf} ")

                        # print('Doc path', doc_path)
                        wordFileName = os.path.split(doc_path)[-1]
                        wordPdf = wordFileName
                        dest_pathWord = os.path.join(newFolderPath, wordPdf)
                        shutil.move(doc_path, dest_pathWord)

                        # print(f"Imzali Report File has been moved to its destination. src: {doc_path}, destination: {dest_pathWord} ")


                    elif 'GENERATED-REPORT' not in doc_path and '-IMZALIRAPOR' not in doc_path and '@' not in doc_path:
                        # Here pdf convertion happens.
                        doc2pdf(doc_path, pdf_path)
                        # Create subFolder based on PDF file.
                        createFolderPath = os.path.split(pdf_path)[-1].split(".")[0]

                        try:
                            newFolderPath = createFolder(baseAd, createFolderPath)
                        except Exception as error:
                            createText('buAnaModel', f'{error}')

                        # print(f"New folder has been created: {newFolderPath}")
                        pdfFileName = os.path.split(pdf_path)[-1]

                        src_pdf = pdf_path
                        dest_pathPdf = os.path.join(newFolderPath, pdfFileName)
                        shutil.move(src_pdf, dest_pathPdf)
                        # print(f"File has been moved to its destination. src: {src_pdf}, destination: {dest_pathPdf} ")

                        # print('Doc path', doc_path)
                        wordFileName = os.path.split(doc_path)[-1]
                        wordPdf = wordFileName
                        dest_pathWord = os.path.join(newFolderPath, wordPdf)
                        shutil.move(doc_path, dest_pathWord)

                        # print(f"File has been moved to its destination. src: {doc_path}, destination: {dest_pathWord} ")

                except Exception as e:
                    createText('exceptionHasOccured...', f'{e}')

            print(f"{currentFileName} FINISHED")

        elif event.event_type == 'created' and '@' in currentFileNameSplitted and not outer_is_temporary_file(
                file_to_process):
            print(f"{currentFileName} ATTACHMENT STARTED")

            doc_path = file_to_process
            folderPath = currentFileNameSplitted.split("@")[1].split(".")[0]

            try:
                baseFolderPath = os.path.split(doc_path)[:-1][0]
                # print(f"Attachments detected: {doc_path}, {currentFileNameSplitted}, {baseFolderPath}")
                dest_path = os.path.join(baseFolderPath, folderPath, currentFileNameSplitted)
                try:
                    shutil.move(doc_path, dest_path)
                    print(f"{currentFileName} ATTACHMENT MOVED")
                except:
                    try:
                        createFolderAtt(os.path.join(baseFolderPath, folderPath))
                        shutil.move(doc_path, dest_path)
                        print(f"{currentFileName} ATTACHMENT MOVED")
                    except Exception as e:
                        createText('InnerAttachmentError', f'{e}')
            except Exception as e:
                createText('outerAttachmentErrorOccured', f'{e}')

    except Exception as e:
        createText('outerAllExceptionasOccured', f'{e}')

class DocFileHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, executor):
        """executor is a multiprocessing pool."""

        super().__init__()
        self.executor = executor

    def is_temporary_file(self, filename):
        return filename.startswith("~$")

    def on_created(self, event):
        def done_callback(future):
            try:
                future.result()
            except Exception as e:
                print('Exception doing conversion:', e)


        file_to_process = event.src_path
        print(event, file_to_process)
        if not (self.is_temporary_file(os.path.basename(file_to_process))
                or file_to_process.endswith('.tmp')
                or event.is_directory
                or os.path.basename(file_to_process).startswith("~$")
        ):
            print('File has been sent', event)
            future = self.executor.submit(mainConverter, event)
            future.add_done_callback(done_callback)


def main():
    pool_size = os.cpu_count() or 1

    with PoolExecutor(pool_size) as executor:
        directory_to_watch = baseAd
        event_handler = DocFileHandler(executor)

        observer = Observer()
        observer.schedule(event_handler, path=directory_to_watch, recursive=False)
        observer.start()

        input('Hit Enter to terminate: ')
        observer.stop()
        observer.join()

    # Implciitly wait for all submitted conversions to complete
    # (a call to executor.shutdown() will be made):


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After starting up the program (having first set `baseAd = r"C:\Booboo\test\uploads"`) and then copying to this directory files *application.docx* and *Program.docx*, the following is printed:

```None
Hit Enter to terminate: FileCreatedEvent(src_path='C:\\Booboo\\test\\uploads\\application.docx', dest_path='', event_type='created', is_directory=False, is_synthetic=False) C:\Booboo\test\uploads\application.docx
File has been sent FileCreatedEvent(src_path='C:\\Booboo\\test\\uploads\\application.docx', dest_path='', event_type='created', is_directory=False, is_synthetic=False)
FileCreatedEvent(src_path='C:\\Booboo\\test\\uploads\\Program.docx', dest_path='', event_type='created', is_directory=False, is_synthetic=False) C:\Booboo\test\uploads\Program.docx
File has been sent FileCreatedEvent(src_path='C:\\Booboo\\test\\uploads\\Program.docx', dest_path='', event_type='created', is_directory=False, is_synthetic=False)
('C:\\Booboo\\test\\uploads', 'application.docx') STARTED
('C:\\Booboo\\test\\uploads', 'Program.docx') STARTED
FileCreatedEvent(src_path='C:\\Booboo\\test\\uploads\\~$plication.docx', dest_path='', event_type='created', is_directory=False, is_synthetic=False) C:\Booboo\test\uploads\~$plication.docx
FileCreatedEvent(src_path='C:\\Booboo\\test\\uploads\\~$rogram.docx', dest_path='', event_type='created', is_directory=False, is_synthetic=False) C:\Booboo\test\uploads\~$rogram.docx
FileCreatedEvent(src_path='C:\\Booboo\\test\\uploads\\msoAE80.tmp', dest_path='', event_type='created', is_directory=False, is_synthetic=False) C:\Booboo\test\uploads\msoAE80.tmp
FileCreatedEvent(src_path='C:\\Booboo\\test\\uploads\\msoAE81.tmp', dest_path='', event_type='created', is_directory=False, is_synthetic=False) C:\Booboo\test\uploads\msoAE81.tmp
FileCreatedEvent(src_path='C:\\Booboo\\test\\uploads\\msoAF2E.tmp', dest_path='', event_type='created', is_directory=False, is_synthetic=False) C:\Booboo\test\uploads\msoAF2E.tmp
FileCreatedEvent(src_path='C:\\Booboo\\test\\uploads\\~WRD0000.tmp', dest_path='', event_type='created', is_directory=False, is_synthetic=False) C:\Booboo\test\uploads\~WRD0000.tmp
FileCreatedEvent(src_path='C:\\Booboo\\test\\uploads\\msoB111.tmp', dest_path='', event_type='created', is_directory=False, is_synthetic=False) C:\Booboo\test\uploads\msoB111.tmp
FileCreatedEvent(src_path='C:\\Booboo\\test\\uploads\\~WRD0001.tmp', dest_path='', event_type='created', is_directory=False, is_synthetic=False) C:\Booboo\test\uploads\~WRD0001.tmp
DirCreatedEvent(src_path='C:\\Booboo\\test\\uploads\\application', dest_path='', event_type='created', is_directory=True, is_synthetic=False) C:\Booboo\test\uploads\application
('C:\\Booboo\\test\\uploads', 'application.docx') FINISHED
('C:\\Booboo\\test\\uploads', 'Program.docx') FINISHED
DirCreatedEvent(src_path='C:\\Booboo\\test\\uploads\\Program', dest_path='', event_type='created', is_directory=True, is_synthetic=False) C:\Booboo\test\uploads\Program
```

Comment: Hey i just tried this, it does not work. I will try to modify it tomorrow and see what happens.

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: It waited for me to press Enter to do the conversion i changed it to while true to check the folder all the time. Now i am doing some tests do understand if all works correct.

Comment: That is surprising. Hitting enter is meant to terminate the program after any current conversions in progress are completed. Your code expects the user to type Ctrl-C, but that is not handled in your child processes/threads. If you have `while True: pass`, you are burning up CPU cycles non-productively. On my Windows platform the conversions run as expected.

Comment: I have added sample output to my answer demonstrating that the conversions start and complete without first hitting Enter.

Comment: I have added my output to the question.

Comment: **Are you sure that you are running my code exactly without any changes?** I see that the event passed to your `DocFileHandler.on_created` method prints out differently than mine and so you might be running a different version of module `watchdog`, I have the latest 4.0.0 version. If you don't then run `pip install --upgrade watchdog`. Likewise, I am also running version 306 of `pywin32`. But it's not clear to me that updating to the latest versions of these modules will make a difference, but I can't think of anything else.

Comment: By hitting Enter, you are terminating the watchdog observer. So the only thing I can think of is that somehow it's running is preventing the submitted tasks from executing. Again, I can't see why that would be the case.